# How do I make sure my IM client is using the right SSL certificate?

Tags: security, instant-messaging, ssl

Google's had [fraudulent SSL certificates issued for their domains](http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2011/08/29/fraudulent-google-com-certificate/).

[image]

So, the question I have is, "How do I make sure Pidgin/Empathy trust the correct certificate?"

Comment: **DO NOT** accept a self-signed certificate from Google!

Comment: In fact, **DO NOT** accept a self-signed certificate from **anyone**, unless you are *perfectly, 100%, absolutely* sure what you're doing (which is the exact opposite of "naah, what could possibly happen?" or "meh, some guy on teh intarwebs sez it's okay").

Comment: Thanks George, Piskvor, but that isn't an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really comes down to; who do you really trust? I personally would create my own self-signed certificate and would simply use that one. This is because **I Know** I created it and I was not relying on a third-party that could be or will be compromised. So then you would just need to trust yourself;)